# Update just particular Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, ide, updates

Checking for updates in Eclipse sometimes takes quite some time. Is there any way to check for just particular plugin/feature whether there is a new update available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From *About -> Installation Details -> Features* you can check for updates on single features (which is what you meant, because the Eclipse deployment system thinks in features, not plugins).

However, to get around that long waiting time, I would recommend to use *Preferences -> Install -> Automatic Update* and schedule a regular (weekly?) check. That way you don't have to wait at all and also will not forget checking for updates.